What should I do about the large volume of "Not indexed" URLs showing up in Webmaster Tools?
I run a WordPress website focused on board gaming. We've got thousands of good URLs: Webmaster Tools shows 14k indexed pages. But I'm more concerned by the 46k not-indexed pages.

I believe that most of these are bad URLs as evidenced by the "reasons" and example URLs also provided by Webmaster Tools.


My question is what is the best approach to removing these bad URLs from consideration? As far as I know, I'm not publishing them - by that I mean they don't appear anywhere on my website. So it's either crawlers trying to find a vulnerability, or some other automated tool. The volume is concerning, but I feel more concerned about what to do with them. At the moment I have a combination of WordPress auto-forwarding these URLs to the canonical URLs, and several regexes in place for known patterns.
Since I don't know where these URLs are coming from, would it be better to simply return a hard 404 instead of a redirect. I basically don't want Google to know about any of those
A secondary question, but one which might be better asked on the Wordpress SO forum, would be "where are these URLs coming from"?
